# RTE Field Text Direction

Tags: rte

i recently updated my system from 5 to 6  , but i found that the text direction option in RTE field is removed in EE6 , what can i do to change the RTE field writing direction ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for getting in touch about this.

We're planning to add much broader RTL support to ExpressoinEngine in the near future.  It might be worth checking out this PR in github.

https://packettide.atlassian.net/browse/EECORE-1810

On the RTE its self, we also have a ticket internally to look at RTL support as part of this larger RTL scope.

Thanks,

-Tom Jaeger